# Center tapped rectifier

Tags: transformer, rectifier

Hi I am new to electronics and I want to know is there any difference, using different ratings of an electrolytic capacitor, can I use any 50/100/200/400Volts etc and 1000/2000/4700/10,000uF etc to make a Center tapped rectifier for a 24_0_24 VDC toroidal transformer. Last week I made one but the rectifier gets hot within second, I used this diagram

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The parts I used to make the rectifier are "four IN5408-diodes and two electrolytic capacitor 25volts 4700uf, I have tested the rectifier on a 12_0_12 VDC laminated transformer but the rectifier gets hot, so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

This is the transformer.
https://i.imgsafe.org/6c5e203e9a.jpg

will a 200/250 VDC cap work, if not will this cap work.
https://www.eightaudio.in/products/elna-4700uf-63v-aluminium-electrolytic-capacitor?variant=17590826756

Thank you.

Comment: Your reference photo has the bridge rectifier diodes with incorrect polarity. Sigh. The web is not always right. Find a more reliable reference. Hope your transformer is still OK.

Comment: Try understanding a schematic before building it, saves components

Comment: @glen_geek yes thank God the transformer is still working(:

Answer (score 4):

Should be like this (the schematic is wrong, your diodes are shorting out the transformer and possibly preventing your caps from violently venting from overvoltage abuse):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdnQEK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1N54XX rectifiers are pretty rugged, they may have survived, but I suggest using new ones because if they have failed they will likely fail short and can damage the ones that are not already fried. They're also really inexpensive. If you do try to re-use them, test them with the diode function on your multimeter before wiring them in.

As noted you should use a capacitor voltage rating that is at least 20% ~ 30% higher than \$\sqrt2\$ times the RMS voltage of your transformer winding, so for a 24V:24V winding, use 50V caps. 35V caps are too close- the transformer will have a higher voltage when lightly loaded and the line voltage may be a bit high at some times of day.

The capacitance you need will depend on your maximum load and the maximum output ripple you can tolerate. A good estimate of the peak-to-peak ripple is:

\$V_R= \frac{I_{load}T_C}{C}\$ with C in Farads, Iload in Amperes and Tc is 0.0083 for 60Hz or 0.01 for 50Hz mains using full wave rectification as you have.

Comment: OK i will rebuild the rectifiers again BTW yes the parts i use are from an old Philips cassette/audio CD player which was in good working condition but i don't use it anymore it was just laying around doing nothing, so i took the parts apart, anyway thank you so very much for you time and help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the transformer is rated for 24 VAC not DC.  In any case, 24 VAC when rectified will result in a DC voltage of about 33 volts.  With no load other than the capacitors, this could be even higher. This exceeds the ratings of your 25 volt capacitors. Replace the capacitors with higher voltage types (at least 50 VDC) and try again.

Comment: OK i will change the capacitors voltage to 50 VDC. Thank you.

Comment: BTW i have even tested the rectifier on a 12_0_12 laminated transformer but the result is same, the rectifier gets hot within a second. Thank you.

Comment: @Barry has missed the major problem that the bridge rectifier is incorrectly connected.